# Чи є слово “мікрохвильовка” усталеним та самостійним?

Tags: переклад, значення-слів, етимологія

Переглядаючи новини, вчергове наткнувся на вживання в ЗМІ слова "*мікрохвильовка*", наприклад: "[24 канал](https://24tv.ua/mikrohvilovka_mozhe_podaruvati_vam_nizku_nedug_n786714)" і "[Сьогодні](https://ukr.segodnya.ua/lifestyle/food_wellness/chto-nuzhno-znat-o-mikrovolnovkah-1022415.html)", дане слово вказують навіть вже при складенні порад, щодо [догляду](https://stm.net.ua/5637-yak-ochystyty-mikrohvylovku.html).
Без сумніву, що дане слово отримало широко розповсюджене і міцно увійшло в наше сучасне життя, але, чи здобуло воно право бути офіційним або використовуватись при діловій мові, оскільки походить від "*мікрохвильова піч*"?

Зокрема, першочергово, щодо значення слова [звернімося до](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%87) Вікіпедії:

> **Мікрохвильова́ піч** (надвисокочастотна піч, МХП, НВЧ-піч) — побутовий електроприлад для швидкого приготування або швидкого підігріву продуктів харчування, а також для їх розморожування. Мікрохвильова піч є одним з найпопулярніших побутових електроприладів.
>   На відміну від інших пристроїв (як наприклад, духовки або печі) у мікрохвильовій печі розігрів продуктів відбувається не з поверхні, а в більшій частині об'єму, оскільки радіохвилі (на частоті 2,450 ГГц) глибоко проникають майже у всі харчові продукти, унаслідок чого час приготування їжі істотно скорочується.

А от щодо написання та вживання є певні питання:
На "Словотворі" до "*мікрохвильовки*" ще не [добрались](https://slovotvir.org.ua/).
На "Офіційному сайті Української мови" матеріалів теж [немає](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&t=0).
Український правопис [містить](http://www.pravopys.net/#search=%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8C%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%20%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2) тільки вірність написання слова "*мікрохвильовий*". "Вікісловник" теж [не допомагає](https://uk.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&title=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA&fulltext=1&searchToken=5wxqdslbygxpmy793r5kjanss).

А от СУМ-20 [містить](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=193923&page=1635) наступний зміст:

> **МІКРОХВИЛЬО́ВКА**, и, ж., розм. Те саме, що Мікрохвильова́ піч (пі́чка) (див. піч). *Він знову перегнувся за шинквас і заглянув всередину. Підноси з різними чарками і склянками, шейкер, мірна склянка.., мікрохвильовка (В. Хрущак)*; *Таймер, звукові сигнали, спеціальні програми, зручне та зрозуміле меню: у будь-якій мікрохвильовці є все потрібне для швидкого і якісного приготування їжі (із журн.)*.

З якого роблю висновок, що слово хоч і вже закріплене в словнику, але таки отримало примітку як "*розмовне*".

В Glosbe [наводяться](https://uk.glosbe.com/uk/uk/%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) приклади вживання:
*Вчора ми приготували смачну рибу в новій мікрохвильовці.*
*Коли я змішав її з шелдоновим проведінням і спік її у мікрохвильовці мого розуму.*
*...коли ми гріли грейпфрути у мікрохвильовці.*
*Іноді я замислююся над тим, чи навчилися б ми в нашому сьогоденному світі, де все так комфортно—у світі мікрохвильовок, мобільних телефонів, автомобілів з кондиціонерами та затишних будинків—визнавати нашу щоденну залежність від сили Спокути, яка збільшує здібності.*
*Було так весело їсти на обід равіолі, розігріті в мікрохвильовці.*

Отже, підсумовуючи, чи стало слово “мікрохвильовка” усталеним та самостійним?
В діловій мові, літературному написанні вживається словосполучення "мікрохвильова піч", чи вже можна використовувати "мікрохвильовка"?

Comment: Ви ж самі відповідаєте на своє запитання: "слово хоч і вже закріплене в словнику, але таки отримало примітку як "розмовне". Тобто під час спілкування можна використовувати, а от в науковому стилі НЕ варто.

Comment: Пані Оксано, я гадаю, що наведених мною джерел замало, для синтезу відповіді і вирішення заданого питання.

Answer (score 3):

Я погоджуюся із коментарем, що ви вже самі дали відповідь на своє запитання, бо ж слово є в СУМ-20, а це зараз найновіший Тлумачний словник української мови, а отже офіційне джерело. І там воно отримало примітку "розмовний", а це означає, що ми можемо вживати його в розмовній мові та навіть в деяких літературних творах (коли автор зображує простих людей, які не говорять літературною мовою). Однак в документах, наприклад інструкціях, потрібно писати "мікрохвильова піч".

Ось для прикладу одна з таких [інструкцій](https://590.ua/files/instruction/4560.pdf), там ви не знайдете слова "мікрохвильовка". Також не варто казати "мікрохвилівка":

> Часто помилково вважають, що казати "мікрохвилівка" - "українськіше".
>   Це хибна думка. Правильно казати "хвильовий", "хвильова", отже —
>   "хвильовка". В іменниках жіночого роду, утворених від іменників та
>   інших частин мови, вживаємо суфікс -івк(а) [-ївк(а)]: голівка,
>   долівка, маївка, ножівка, полівка, спиртівка, частівка, шалівка,
>   шихтівка. У деяких іменниках уживаємо суфікс -овк(а): головка
>   (капусти), духовка, мікрохвильовка, зарисовка, підготовка. (Див.
>   Український правопис). Термопіч — це не електричне кухонне начиння, їх
>   використовують для обігрівання приміщень, а також для обробки речовин
>   та матеріалів.

Таку інформацію я знайшов на сайті [Gazeta.ua](https://gazeta.ua/articles/chistota-movlennya/_mova-i-moda-dorobivshi-ukrayinskij-interfejs-internetmagazin-navchaye-gramotnosti/580043), сама ж вона посилається на тест від мережі магазинів побутової техніки "Comfy", який в свою чергу посилається на онлайн-правопис, словники або ж працю мовознавця Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича "Як ми говоримо".

Answer (score 0):

Мікрохвилівка - тепер без запитань і офіційно. https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/

[image: мікрохвилівка]

Comment: Я додав скріншот до вашої відповіді, бо ваше посилання не веде на статтю і цей онлайн-словник не дозволяє робити прямі посилання. Взагалі відповідь за допомогою посилання без пояснень і хоча б мінімального опису того що міститься за посиланням вважається неякісною через те, що через деякий час робоче посилання може стати неробочим і вже не буде можливості прочитати інформацію що там містилася.